# Greek letters in Octave plot not exporting to EPS

Tags: plot, octave

I can't make Octave export my EPS figures with the greek symbols in title. I mean, it **does** displays inside Octave, but when I print it to an EPS file (`print -depsc2 filename.eps`), it displays *alpha* instead of the *symbol* alpha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want the EPS for inclusion into a latex document? There are numerous ways to do this. One popular way is using psfrag.

I suggest using

```
print -depslatex yourfile.eps
```

which will create yourfile.eps only with the graphic part and yourfile.tex (which includes yourfile.eps). You can then add it to your main latex document with \include.

If you just want the plot without having a main latex document you can use
    print -depslatexstandalone yourfile.eps
and let latex process the code. Here is a simple example:

```
close all
graphics_toolkit fltk
sombrero ();
title ("Plot the familiar 3-D sombrero function:\
$z = \\frac{\\sin\\left(\\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\\right)}{\\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$");
print -depslatexstandalone test_epslatex

system("latexmk test_epslatex.tex -ps");
system("latexmk -c");
```

With this you have a great flexibility and use all Latex commands.

Another, very easy way is to use gnuplot:

```
graphics_toolkit gnuplot
plot(1:2);
title('\alpha')
print -depsc out.eps
```

Comment: Thanks! May you explain the difference with `-depslatexstandalone`?

Comment: print -depslatex creates a .tex file which is intent to be included in another .tex file, for example an article or book written with Latex. print -depslatexstandalone create a .tex file which can be directly compiled with latex